# Django: ImageField Unknown Field

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I currently have a django project I am working on and I extended the user profile successfully, however I would like to allow the user to have a profile picture so I added the following code:
Models.py:

```
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/profile/%Y/%m/')
```

and in my forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profile_pic')
```

and here is the code for my views:

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

However when I go to the profile page now, I am presented with the following:

> Django Version:   1.6.2
>
> Exception Type:   FieldError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> Unknown field(s) (profile_pic) specified for UserProfile

Any ideas? I am pretty new to the django framework.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No comma in `fields = ('profile_pic')` need to be `fields = ('profile_pic',)`

Comment: and try to check in db if column `profile_pic` exists